# How to create polylines from a point Feature Class linking all points using arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, points-to-line

I want to create polylines linking a bunch of points. Individual polylines must be created between every point. I started by reading the x & y cords and then created unique pairs as well as all combinations. Unfortunately my python is lacking and I'm also stuck with ArcGIS 10.0.

```
import arcpy
import itertools
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

myt = ()
newt = ()
pairt = ()

# Get the XY coords from the point featureclass
inputfc = 'C:\\Temp\\testing.gdb\\BunchofPoints'
desc = arcpy.Describe(infc)
shapename = desc.ShapeFieldName
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(inputfc)
for row in rows:
    feat = row.getValue(shapename)
    pnt = feat.getPart()
    myt = myt +((pnt.X),(pnt.Y))

#Create pairs
newt =zip(myt[::2],myt[1::2])

#Create combinations
for pair in itertools.combinations(newt,2):
    pairt = pairt + pair

#Check
print pairt

#Create lines
mypoint = arcpy.Point()
myarray = arcpy.Array()
featList = []
for feature in pairt:
    for coPair in feature:
        mypoint.X = coPair[0]
        mypoint.Y = coPair[1]
        myarray.add(mypoint)
    polyline = arcpy.Polyline(myarray)
    myarray.removeAll()
    featList.append(polyline)
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(featureList, 'C:\\Temp\\all_lines.shp')
```

I get the following error:
    Runtime error : 'float' object is unsubscriptable

I'm struggling with how to read the pair of coordinates I've created and also with creating the individual lines.

Comment: print pairt   does it make it that far and if so what is the output? and you are using and empty tuple to collect the points, why not a list?

Comment: yes it prints as so:   ((-4416739.9874999998, 1752062.4517000001), (-211810.60020000022, -2405686.8023000006)), ((-4416739.9874999998, 1752062.4517000001), (283580.80020000041, 47680.133300000802))...etc ....although admittedly I'm not sure how to deal with this output....

Comment: @wunderkind - the output from 'pairt' is a list of coordinate pairs.  when you use `for feature in pairt:` you step through each pair of coordinates (feature) and add to your point array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a couple of errors in your code:
`desc = arcpy.Describe(infc)` should be `desc = arcpy.Describe(inputfc)`
You've used "infc" instead of "inputfc"

```
for feature in pairt:
    for coPair in feature:
        mypoint.X = coPair[0]
        mypoint.Y = coPair[1]
        myarray.add(mypoint)
    polyline = arcpy.Polyline(myarray)
    myarray.removeAll()
    featList.append(polyline)
```

should be:

```
for feature in pairt:
    mypoint.X = feature [0]
    mypoint.Y = feature [1]
    myarray.add(mypoint)
polyline = arcpy.Polyline(myarray)
myarray.removeAll()
featList.append(polyline)
```

feature is your pair of coordinates, so `feature[0]` is x and `feature[1]` is y.  The `copair[0]` won't work as there is no pair of coordinates in the list.

`arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(featureList, 'C:\\Temp\\all_lines.shp')` should be `arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(featList, 'C:\\Temp\\all_lines.shp')`
You used 'featureList' rather than 'featList'

This produces an output for me joining each point to every other point. [image: Points to Lines]

Complete code that worked for me:

```
import arcpy
import itertools
#mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

myt = ()
newt = ()
pairt = ()

# Get the XY coords from the point featureclass
inputfc = 'C:\\Temp\\testing.gdb\\BunchofPoints'
desc = arcpy.Describe(inputfc)
shapename = desc.ShapeFieldName
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(inputfc)
for row in rows:
    feat = row.getValue(shapename)
    pnt = feat.getPart()
    myt = myt +((pnt.X),(pnt.Y))

#Create pairs
newt =zip(myt[::2],myt[1::2])

#Create combinations
for pair in itertools.combinations(newt,2):
    pairt = pairt + pair

#Check
print pairt

#Create lines
mypoint = arcpy.Point()
myarray = arcpy.Array()
featList = []

for feature in pairt:
    mypoint.X = feature[0]
    mypoint.Y = feature[1]
    myarray.add(mypoint)

polyline = arcpy.Polyline(myarray)
myarray.removeAll()
featList.append(polyline)

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(featList, 'C:\\Temp\\all_lines.shp')
```

Comment: Fantastic! I really appreciate the help. I had changed the code before posting to conceal the 'real' paths and FCs but this obviously introduced errors. It is good to know that I was on the right path though...thanks again!

Comment: How do I create separate line 'connectors' rather than a single line? how can I use feature[a,b] to select the pairs and create the lines?

Comment: Solved! I used the size of the array equal to 2 to create each segment.